# How do I add text to a cycling button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've made a script that makes a grid of buttons, and I do not know how to add text to those buttons when someone presses them (so that one click is X and two clicks is O)
Here's the code:

```
def cycler(button):
    color_list = ['white', 'turquoise', 'crimson', 'grey']
    def cycle():
        index = color_list.index(button['background'])
        index = (index + 1) % len(color_list)
        button['background'] = color_list[index]
    return cycle
grd = Tk()
grd.title ("Grid Game")
frame = Frame(grd)
grd.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
grd.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")
grid = Frame(frame)
grid.grid(sticky="news", column=0, row=7, columnspan=2)
frame.rowconfigure(7, weight=1)
frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
for x in range(15):
    for y in range(5):
        btn = tk.Button(frame, background="white")
        btn['command'] = cycler(btn)
        btn.grid(column=x, row=y, sticky="news")
frame.columnconfigure(tuple(range(15)), weight=1)
frame.rowconfigure(tuple(range(5)), weight=1)
def callback():
    grd.destroy()
button = Button(grd, text="End", command=callback)
button.grid(row=5, column=1)
grd.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can use `button['text']` to set the text, like you set the background color.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a counter to count the number of times the button is clicked. To make the counter cycle between 0 and 1, use `counter %= 2`. To change the text of a button, use the `button.config(text = 'X')` depending on the counter.

This answer may be short due to a lack of clarity in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the button has any text and if it does not then you can add X else add O inside your closure:

```py
def cycler(button):
    def cycle():
        if button['text']:
            button['text'] = 'O'
        else:
            button['text'] = 'X'
    return cycle
```